# Different behaviour using puppeter if loading cookies from local or db

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm building a SaaS in a form of a web scrapper.

This website I'm trying to scrape has a login screen, where I log in and then I store the cookies, session storage and local storage, just so user wouldn't have to log in all over again each time.

In developing I was storing this data on my local disk just for try things out, but now that I'm moving to production, I don't have a way to store this data locally other than database or maybe some other storage service, but I don't want to use a lot of services for this one would like to stick with simple approaches to keep the costs low

But I'm getting different behaviour, if I load all data from local files, and inject them to the browser I would be already logged in when the site loads, but if I load it from my database, I wouldn't be in, I have to log in but this time it wont ask for OTP, it only happen the first time the user logs in, so cookies and all that are been injected successfully using my DB, but for some reason I have to type the username and password again just to log in, the only thing that is working is skipping the OTP screen

This is my local set up - saving data locally

```
const saveCookies = async (page: Page, dirName: string) => {
  const cookiesPath = `./${dirName}/cookies.json`;
  const localStoragePath = `./${dirName}/localStorage.json`;
  const sessionStoragePath = `./${dirName}/sessionStorage.json`;
  
  //Check if directory  ./data exists and create it if not
  try {
    await fs.access(`./${dirName}`, fs.constants.R_OK);
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.code === 'ENOENT') {
      console.log('Directory does not exist.');
      await fs.mkdir(`./${dirName}`);
    } else {
      console.error('Error reading file:', error.message);
    }
  }

  const cookies = JSON.stringify(await page.cookies());
  const localStorage: string = await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(localStorage));
  const sessionStorage: string = await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(sessionStorage));
  
  //Save to local
  await fs.writeFile(cookiesPath, cookies);
  await fs.writeFile(sessionStoragePath, sessionStorage);
  await fs.writeFile(localStoragePath, localStorage);
};
```

And loading locally is

```
const loadCookies = async (page: Page, dirName: string) => {
  console.log('Loading cookies...');

  const cookiesPath = `./${dirName}/cookies.json`;
  const localStoragePath = `./${dirName}/localStorage.json`;
  const sessionStoragePath = `./${dirName}/sessionStorage.json`;

  console.log(cookiesPath, sessionStoragePath, localStoragePath);

  try {
    await fs.access(cookiesPath, fs.constants.R_OK);
    await fs.access(sessionStoragePath, fs.constants.R_OK);
    await fs.access(localStoragePath, fs.constants.R_OK);
    console.log('Files exists...');

    const cookiesString = await fs.readFile(cookiesPath);
    const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString.toString());

    const localStorageString = await fs.readFile(localStoragePath);
    const localStorage = JSON.parse(localStorageString.toString());

    const sessionStorageString = await fs.readFile(sessionStoragePath);
    const sessionStorage = JSON.parse(sessionStorageString.toString());

    console.log('Injecting cookies...');

    await page.setCookie(...cookies);

    await page.evaluate((data) => {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        localStorage[key] = value;
      }
    }, localStorage);

    await page.evaluate((data) => {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        sessionStorage[key] = value;
      }
    }, sessionStorage);

    console.log('Cookies Injected');
    await page.reload();
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.code === 'ENOENT') {
      console.error('Cookies file does not exist.');
    } else {
      console.error('Error reading cookies file:', error.message);
    }

    return null;
  }
};
```

This give me the behaviour I want, that is when the user enter again in the site, he will be automatically log in, without the need of inputting the user and pw again

Now this is the database solution

```
const saveCookies = async (page: Page, userId: string) => {
  const cookies = JSON.stringify(await page.cookies());
  const localStorage: string = await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(localStorage));
  const sessionStorage: string = await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(sessionStorage));
  await db.Cookies.upsert({
    where: {
      userId,
    },
    create: {
      userId,
      cookies,
      localStorage,
      sessionStorage,
    },
    update: {
      cookies,
      localStorage,
      sessionStorage,
    },
  });
};
```

This code successfully stores the data inside my database, they look exactly the same as my local method

And this is how I load them from database:

```
const loadCookies = async (page: Page, userId: string) => {
  console.log('Loading cookies...');
  console.log('Userid', userId);

  try {
    const dataDB = await db.Cookies.findUnique({
      where: {
        userId,
      },
    });

    const cookies = JSON.parse(dataDB?.cookies!);
    const localStorage = JSON.parse(dataDB?.localStorage!);
    const sessionStorage = JSON.parse(dataDB?.sessionStorage!);

    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    console.log('Cookies LOADED');

    await page.evaluate((localStorage) => {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(localStorage)) {
        localStorage[key] = value;
      }
    }, localStorage);
    console.log('LocalStorage LOADED');

    await page.evaluate((sessionStorage) => {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sessionStorage)) {
        sessionStorage[key] = value;
      }
    }, sessionStorage);
    console.log('SessionStorage LOADED');

    console.log('ALL DATA LOADED');

    await page.reload();
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log('Error loading DATA: ' + error.messagee);

    return null;
  }
};
```

It does load them successfully, as I don't get the OTP screen, otherwise I would get an OTP input request.

It would go to the site, and I would be in the login form instead on the landing page already logged in

I'm using nextjs, prisma and typescript